# How can I get specific data from the table using Rselenium?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a table that I believe is using Java script. I want to get the data for indices (i.e., TSX). I would like to get the "Previous day data" for all indices. I am scraping the data using Rselenium but it is unable to locate the element.

Following is my code for scraping previous day data for index called TSX:

```
library(RSelenium)
driver<- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- driver[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("http://bmgfunds.com/interactive-charts/")

elem <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//*[@id='indices-quotes']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

In order to get the Xpath, I inspected the element and copied the Xpath by right clicking in the pan.
I also tried using rvest.

```
library(rvest)

st_table <- read_html("http://bmgfunds.com/interactive-charts/")
table<-html_nodes(st_table, "tbody tr")
```

Unfortunately, I get zero element `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is within an iframe whose source is http://integration.nfusionsolutions.biz/client/bullionmanagementgroup/module/quotechartfull, so you can grab the table from there:

```
st_table <- read_html("http://integration.nfusionsolutions.biz/client/bullionmanagementgroup/module/quotechartfull") 
(table <- html_table(st_table)[[3]])
```

This code grabs all the tables from the previous url with `html_table` and selects the table that you want (which is the third element of the list).